# Create query which selects by checking items in related list

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have `Shop` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="shop_id")
private List<OpenDay> openDays = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and `OpenDay` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "open_day")
public class OpenDay {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private LocalDate date;
}
```

I need a query which will select all `Shop` which have `OpenDay` with `date` set to particular dates, let's say for today and tomorrow so I select shops which are open today and tomorrow.
How can I achieve this?
Criteria API is preferred so I will be able to use it with spring-data-jpa `Specification`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand `open_day` table contains `shop_id` column. So I suggest you to add `Shop` field to `OpenDay` entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "open_day")
public class OpenDay {          
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private LocalDate date;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="shop_id")
   private Shop shop;
}
```

And then

```
EntityManager entityManager;

public List<Shop> getShopsByOpenDates(List<LocalDate> dates) {
   CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<Shop> query = builder.createQuery(Shop.class);
   Root<OpenDay> openDay = query.from(OpenDay.class);

   Predicate predicate = openDay.get("date").in(dates);

   query.select(openDay.get("shop")).distinct(true).where(predicate);

   return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```